# Correct time recording between two events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

OK. I've been thinking about this for this whole day and probably lost the overview and would never come up with the solution.

Background: my script (extract below) shows "WORD" repeatedly (quick fadeIn, variable fadeOut) and records the elapsed time between appearance and keypress. See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8VHR5/5/)

However, I think my t1 and t2 are not placed/timed exactly accurate. What I want is this: it should record the elapsed time *exactly from the appearance* to keypress and the WORD should be shown always for 1500ms (unless keypress breaks the interval), so the theoretical max reaction time is 1499ms.

I suspect that my variable randomisi is an issue there, isn't it? I tried to take this into account but got negative reaction times sometimes.

```
var isi = [250, 500, 750]; var RT = [];
var showwords = function() {
    var randomisi = isi[Math.floor((Math.random() * isi.length))];

    $("#words").fadeOut(randomisi, function() {
        $("#words").text("WORD").fadeIn(10);
    });

    t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
};


INT = setInterval(showwords, 1500);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    clearInterval(INT);
    var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    reac = t2 - t1;RT.push(reac); $("#RT").val(RT);
    t1 = t2;
    INT = setInterval(showwords, 1500);
});
```

Can someone shed light on this for me now too complicated timing issue?

Comment: What is not functioning as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the three things *off* in your script appears to be this part

```
$("#words").fadeOut(randomisi, function() {
    $("#words").text("WORD").fadeIn(10);
});

t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
```

`.fadeOut` doesn't actually block the script so `t1` is set even as the previous word is fading out giving you a large `RT` value.
Relacing this code with

```
$("#words").fadeOut(randomisi, function() {
    $("#words").text("WORD").fadeIn(10, function(){
        t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
    });
});
```

will solve issue 1.

2nd issue is that it keeps listening for keydown even when the word is fading out. You can prevent this by adding a new flag to your code.

**Your code after fix1 and fix2**

```
var isi = [250, 500, 750],
    RT = [],
    listen = false;

var showwords = function () {
    listen = false;
    var randomisi = isi[Math.floor((Math.random() * isi.length))];
    $("#words").fadeOut(randomisi, function () {
        $("#words").text("WORD").fadeIn(10, function () {
            t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
            listen = true;
        });
    });
};

INT = setInterval(showwords, 1500);
$(document).keypress(function (e) {

    if(listen == false) return;

    clearInterval(INT);

    var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    reac = t2 - t1;
    RT.push(reac);
    $("#RT").val(RT);
    INT = setInterval(showwords, 1500);
});
```

3rd issue appears to be the the word will appear for `1500 - randomisi - 10` ms instead of exactly 1500ms.

Comment: This is great and 1 and 2 work perfectly. Thank you. I just tried to set the Interval dynamically with the variable randomisi. But I don't seem to be access the 'most recent' randomisi for the interval outside the showwords function. Any idea?

Comment: make it a global variable instead of function's private variable i.e., remove `var` beside `randomisi` (line 7) and place `var randomisi = isi[Math.floor((Math.random() * isi.length))];` after `RT = [],` line 2)

Comment: but using same `randomisi` value for both `setInterval` and `.fadeout` will create unintended results because the new word needs `(randomisi + 10)ms` to fully appear but you'll be switching word every `randomisi`ms. I would `setInterval` every `randomisi * 2`ms

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see other than negative clock skew that could result in `t2` being less that `t1` is if the javascript implementation is multithreaded and `showwords` is already being executed when the keypress event fires, and `t1` is updated by `showwords` after `t2` is set by the keypress handler, but before `reac` is calculated.

If you add a lock variable to eliminate that possibility, you can confirm or rule out that possibility:

```
var isi = [250, 500, 750]; var RT = [];
var inShowWords = 0;
var showwords = function() {
    inShowWords = 1;
    var randomisi = isi[Math.floor((Math.random() * isi.length))];

    $("#words").fadeOut(randomisi, function() {
        $("#words").text("WORD").fadeIn(10);
    });

    t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
    inShowWords = 0;
};


INT = setInterval(showwords, 1500);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (inShowWords == 0) {
        clearInterval(INT);
        var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
        reac = t2 - t1;RT.push(reac); $("#RT").val(RT);
        t1 = t2;
        INT = setInterval(showwords, 1500);
    } else {
        RT.push('locked'); $("#RT").val(RT);
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution. It could be improved by (1) declaring both `t1` and `INT` at the top and (2) moving `t1 = (new Date()).getTime() ( eqv. t1 = Date.now() )` into the `.fadeOut()` callback so it starts as soon as `.fadeIn()` starts.